# merge second array with first array by comparing properties and add properties to objects in first array if object is not part of second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have three arrays. Array1 : fields, Array2: config, Array3: defaultChartType

I need to compare 'name' attribute from field array objects with 'measures' of config array object. If matches, the config object should be updated with label of fields object. 
If any name attribute object from fields does not exists in config object, then it should be added to config array as new object with defaultchatType object in it.

```
  fields.map((measure) => {
        let Measures = [];
         Measures = config.map((k) =>
            k.measures.map((val) => {
             if (measure.name.indexOf(val) < 0) return null;
            return k;
          })
         );

        console.log(Measures, 'measuresmeasures');

      return null;
    });

var defaultChartType={
type:"line",
 line: {
      color: '#00ADFF',
      width: 4,
    },
 }


var fields= [
    {
      name: ['Book1History','Book1Projected'],
      label: 'Book1',

    },
    {
      name: ['Book2Projected'],
      label: 'Book2',

    },
        {
        name: ['Book3History','Book3Projected'],
        label: 'Book3',

        },
        {
        name: ['Book4'],
        label: 'Book4',

        }
  ]
 var config= [
  {
    measures: ['Book1History', 'Book1Projected'],
    type: 'line',

  },
  {
    measures: ['Book2Projected'],
    type: 'bar', 
  },
  ]

  var expectedOutput=[
   {
    "measures": [
      "Book1History",
      "Book1Projected"
    ],
    "type": "line",
    "label": "Book1"
    },
  {
"measures": [
  "Book2Projected"
],
"type": "bar",
"label": "Book2"
 },
 {
"measures": [
  "Book3History",
  "Book3Projected"
],
"label": "Book3",
"type": "line",
"line": {
  "color": "#00ADFF",
  "width": "4"
}
},
{
"measures": [
  "Book4"
],
"label": "Book4",
"type": "line",
"line": {
  "color": "#00ADFF",
  "width": "4"
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First using filter and every i am taking out the element from config if any of element from config `measures` matches with `names`.
2. If matches will take out the type from the `found` variable and add it's type to output if not than add default type.

```js
var defaultChartType={type:"line", line: { color: '#00ADFF',width: 4,},}
var fields= [{ name: ['Book1History','Book1Projected'],    label: 'Book1', },{ name: ['Book2Projected'], label: 'Book2', },  { name: ['Book3History','Book3Projected'],        label: 'Book3', }, { name: ['Book4'],label: 'Book4',      } ]
var config= [{measures: ['Book1History', 'Book1Projected'],type: 'line',},{measures: ['Book2Projected'], type: 'bar', },]
 
 let op = fields.map(ele=>{
     let found = config.filter(({measures})=>{
      return measures.every((el,index)=>{
        return el === ele.name[index]
      })
     })
     return{
      ...ele,
      type: found.length ? found[0].type : defaultChartType
     }
 })
 
console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thankyou . this was not exact response though.but it served my purpose to filter. I just placed type as an attrubute,but there are many attributes as such.